# Selenium headless browser gives Cloudflare error when using undetected chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to use Selenium to scrape data off of betonline.ag and when I switch to using a headless browser (need to do this to eventually move script to AWS lambda function) I receive the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\adelu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 246, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: There is no admin configuration!
Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : There is no admin configuration!}
  (Session info: headless chrome=105.0.5195.127)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x006BDF13+2219795]
        Ordinal0 [0x00652841+1779777]
        Ordinal0 [0x0056423D+803389]
        Ordinal0 [0x005BEFFE+1175550]
        Ordinal0 [0x005AE616+1107478]
        Ordinal0 [0x00587F89+950153]
        Ordinal0 [0x00588F56+954198]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x009B2CB2+3040210]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x009A2BB4+2974420]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00756A0A+565546]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00755680+560544]
        Ordinal0 [0x00659A5C+1808988]
        Ordinal0 [0x0065E3A8+1827752]
        Ordinal0 [0x0065E495+1827989]
        Ordinal0 [0x006680A4+1867940]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x77296739+25]
        RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77828FD2+1218]
        RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x77828F9D+1165]
```

Checking one of the div's, I can see that this is a CloudFlare issue:

```python
driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'div')[2].text


'Oops! It’s likely that we’re having\nan internal systems issue\nIf the problem persists, please contact 
customer support so we can help.\nAccess denied\nYou cannot access ultraplay.betonline.ag. Refresh the 
page or contact the site owner to request access.\nRay ID: 74d6c9316f273b7c\nTimestamp: 2022-09-20 
01:28:42 UTC\nYour IP address: ##.###.##.###\nRequested URL: ultraplay.betonline.ag/esports/early-
markets\nError reference number: 1020\nServer ID: FL_106F56\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; 
Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.5195.127 Safari/537.36\nCloudflare Ray 
ID:74d6c9316f273b7c\nPerformance & Security by Cloudflare\nHelp Center'
```

I'm currently using undetected_chromedriver because I was receiving the same error prior to doing this and after I switched to the undetected driver it fixed the issue. Once I tried using a headless browser it started giving me this error and haven't been able to get around it.

Here is my current code:

```python
from math import floor
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import os
import time

EARLY_MARKETS = 'https://ultraplay.betonline.ag/esports/early-markets'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36")

driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(EARLY_MARKETS)
```

Answer (score 0):

In generic version of selenium webdriver, you need to add user agent as the key of the argument instead of just passing the argument string itself:

```
options.add_argument('--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36"')
```

Alternatively, you can use a dict for header as well, and you can add more fields other than User-Agent as well.

```
header = {'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36"}
driver.header_overrides = header
```

Should probably have the double dash in `--start-maximized` too.